# How to open python scripts directly by typing in their name in terminal (Mac OS X)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, python, django

I'm working on installing django and running it on my system.

I have a problem though, in this [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) creating a project is explained by running the command

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

My issue is that this doesn't work. I changed to the directory where django-admin.py is located and ran the command

```
chmod +x django-admin.py
```

with no results. I tried adding the directory with the file to my path without results. I ended up fixing my problem with this command

```
python /location/of/django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

which yielded the outcome I expected. My problem is: What do I need to change/configure such that command

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

would be sufficient?

Here are some experiments:

```
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > django-admin.py startproject mysite
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > ./django-admin.py startproject mysite
-bash: ./django-admin.py: No such file or directory
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > python django-admin.py startproject mysite
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject prufa1
-bash: /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py: /opt/local/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > sudo /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject prufa1Password:
sudo: unable to execute /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py: Permission denied
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > sudo /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject prufa1sudo: unable to execute /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py: Permission denied
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > python /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject prufa1
21:09~/Desktop/HI/NSN/Polls > ls
mysite prufa1
```

Final edit: The problem is solved, see Ian C's answer for the right solution. Thank you everyone for helping my out, this was very fast!

Comment: What happens (e.g. error message) when it "doesn't work"? Adding to path (or explicitly specifying the folder as in `./django-admin.py`) and making it executable should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a slightly more generic version of @Matt Jenkins hashbang (!#) tip you can use to make the script a little more portable. Make sure the first line in the file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
...everything else...
```

That says "look for a program named `python` by searching my `PATH` and run the rest of this script with that program".

You'll also need to set the execute bit on the script with:

```
chmod +x django-admin.py
```

I mention this for completeness, noting that you've already done that.

Finally, the `PATH` variable doesn't actually contain `.` in it (the current working directory). That's a safety precaution and I don't recommend changing that setup (it keeps you from calling `./rm` when you meant the shell's `rm` for example). So you need to call the script with:

```
 ./django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

That says "look in the current working directory for django-admin.py" instead of "search the `PATH` variable" which is what happens if you omit the `./` part.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in the file should contain the program that runs the script prefixed by #! (known as hashbang)

For example:

```
#!/path/to/python
...python code follows...
```

Then you can set the executable bit on the file and the shell will interpret it as a script using the program found in the first line as the interpreter.

This is often used with shell scripts, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

for FILE in `ls`
{
    echo "Filename: ${FILE}"
}
```

Comment: The head of the script already said #!/path/to/python so I don't understand why it doesn't work >_< (It had the correct path just to prevent misunderstanding)

Comment: Is the path to python the right path to python?  Check with __whereis python__

Comment: Yes it's the right path.

Comment: Well, now I'm flummoxed...

Comment: Ah, I think I see what's going on here.  The file you're trying to run isn't in a known place (i.e., not in your path) but in /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/  You need to add /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin/ to your $PATH environment variable, then you can call it just by name.

Comment: Sorry, I found the solution, I had a . in the path definition as pointed out by Ian C, can't understand how I didn't see that... >_< thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the file in the **Finder** by clicking it once.
2. From the **File** menu, select **Get Info**.
3. In the Info window, click the triangle next to "**Open with**:" to expand that section of the window.
4. From the pull-down menu that appears, **select the application** you wish to use to open the file.

— **Source:** [Indiana University - KB: How do I assign an application to open certain file types?](https://kb.iu.edu/data/akvs.html)

Comment: What application should I choose to open the file? I'm using python 2.4 with Django 1.2.4. I also don't see how this is relevant to running the command in terminal.

Comment: @Haffi112: Python. As for command line, you need the [shebang](http://superuser.com/questions/251947/how-to-open-python-scripts-directly-by-typing-in-their-name-in-terminal-mac-os-x/251956#251956)...

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, it still doesn't work =/

Answer (score 0):

When you change the file django-admin.py permissions, you have to write this:

sudo chmod +x django-admin.py

Works for me

Comment: The problem appears to be with the `#!` line, not with the permissions of the script file.